When I clicks on signup button Google OAuth automatically redirects to successRedirect even if I logged out
server.js
import connectDB from './db/connection.js'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import express from 'express'
import authRouter from './routes/auth.route.js'
import session from 'express-session'
import cors from 'cors'
import passport from 'passport'
import { oAuthConfig } from './middlewares/passport.js'

const app = express()
dotenv.config()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000



app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:5000',
    credentials: true,
}))



app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
        secure: false,
    }
}))

oAuthConfig()
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())


passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user)
})

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user)
})

app.use('/auth', authRouter)



app.listen(PORT, () => {
    connectDB()
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`)
})

passport.js
import passport from 'passport';
import { Strategy as GoogleStrategy } from 'passport-google-oauth20';
import User from '../models/user.model.js';

export const oAuthConfig = (req,res) => {
    passport.use(
        new GoogleStrategy({
            clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
            callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
            scope: ['profile', 'email'],
            prompt: 'select_account'
        },
            async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
                try {
                    let user = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });

                    if (!user) {
                        user = new User({
                            googleId: profile.id,
                            displayName: profile.displayName,
                            email: profile.emails[0].value,
                            image: profile.photos[0].value
                        });
                        await user.save();
                        
                    }
                    return done(null, user);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log("ERROR IN PASSPORT.JS ",error);
                    return done(error, null);
                }
            })
    );
}

auth.route.js
import express from 'express'
import { login, logout, signupWithGoogle, googleAuthCallback } from '../controllers/auth.controller.js'


const router = express.Router()

router.get('/google', signupWithGoogle,(req,res)=>{
    console.log("SESSION : ",req.session)
    console.log("USER : ", req.user)
})
router.get('/google/callback', googleAuthCallback,(req,res)=>{
    console.log("SESSION : ",req.session)
    console.log("USER : ", req.user)
    res.status(200).json(req.user)
})

router.get('/login', login)
router.get('/logout', logout)


export default router

auth.controller.js
import passport from 'passport';

export const signupWithGoogle = passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] })
export const googleAuthCallback = passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login', session: false })

export const login = async (req, res) => {
        console.log("SESSION : ", req.session)
}

export const logout = async (req, res) => {
        try {

                req.logout((err) => {
                        req.session.regenerate(() => {
                                res.redirect('/login');
                        });
                });

        } catch (error) {
                console.log('Something went wrong.', error.message)
                res.status(500).json({ message: 'Something went wrong.' })
        }
}

I use react.js for frontend. The server and frontent is running in two different ports.
Whenever I click signup button, google OAuth doesn't even show the choose account section. I tried adding prompt: 'select_acccounts but it didn't solved the problem.
When I logout from my account and then I click signin button it should show the select account google window. Please help me to solve this problem.
